# Riemann integral and fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: real-analysis

My statement in textbook is Suppose $H(x) = \int_{a}^{x} h(t) dt$ is differentiable at $c \in [a,b]$, then $h$ is continuous at c. I tried to provide a counter-example by considering the piecewise function: 
 $h : [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ 
$$ h(x) = \begin{cases} 
1 & , x <0 \\ 
-1 &, x \geq 0 
 \end{cases}$$
Is there something wrong with this?

Comment: Your book has a serious mistake. The theorem is *if $h$ is continuous at $c$ then $H$ is differentiable at $c$* and not the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

We get $$H=\begin{cases}1+x&x<0\\1-x&x\geq0.\end{cases}$$
This function is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: More simply, that is $1-|x|$.